# NDTM for Graph Clique Problem in poly-time

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism, clique

I am having a doubt. This is my NDTM algorithm:

GCP(G, k):

- generate a list with k distinct nodes from graph G
- generate an adjacency matrix, fill it with 1 if an edge exist, 0 otherwise
- check if every row has only 1-s, hence return *Yes*, otherwise *No*

Does this run in poly-time? I guess so since in my idea building a matrix takes $n^2$ time.

Is there any flaw in this?

Comment: What have you tried?  The way to tell whether your algorithm is correct is to try to prove it correct.  Have you tried proving it correct?  What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using *generate* for two different actions, your second bullet is not explained correctly, and your third bullet always fails. Here is a better version of your algorithm:

- Non-deterministically generate a list of $k$ distinct nodes of $G$: $v_1,\ldots,v_k$.
- Calculate the $k\times k$ matrix $B$ given by $B(i,j) = A(v_i,v_j)$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$.
- Return *Yes* if all off-diagonal entries of $B$ are 1. Otherwise return *No*.

What is the running time of the algorithm? This depends on your exact model of computation. However, choosing $k$ nodes takes polynomial time, calculating the $k\times k$ matrix takes polynomial time, and checking all its off-diagonal entries takes polynomial time. So in total, the algorithm runs in polynomial time.

Why do we need the matrix $B$? We don't. We could simplify the pseudocode:

- Non-deterministically generate a list of $k$ distinct nodes of $G$: $v_1,\ldots,v_k$.
- If $A(v_i,v_j) = 1$ for all $1 \leq i < j \leq k$ then return *Yes*, otherwise return *No*.

Now for a more interesting question. How much *space* does your algorithm take? It takes space $\Theta(k\log n)$ (since you need $\log n$ bits to store each index), and so in the worst case, $\Theta(n\log n)$. Can you do better? Say, can you do the verification in $O(\log n)$ space? If you could, then you would have shown that clique is in NL. Since NL is in P, this would imply that P=NP (since clique is NP-complete), which is considered unlikely. So you probably need more than $\omega(\log n)$ space. But how much more?

Comment: can you define off-diagonals? (Thanks a lot for your last question)

Comment: An off-diagonal entry is any entry which is not on the diagonal.